# How can I integrate the "send and wait for reply" functionality of a Twilio Flow widget with the Twilio Message Service?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flow

I am currently utilizing Twilio Flow to construct a reminder system. Everything was functioning smoothly until the completion of my Application-to-Person (A2P) verification. The existing scenario is as follows:

1. A2P verification necessitates the inclusion of the phone number within the Message Service as a sender. However, this adjustment disrupts the expected behavior of the "send and wait for reply" flow widget. Typically, after sending a message to the user, the flow enters a pause state, awaiting the user's response. Presently, the response message triggers an alternate flow, bypassing the intended continuation of the initial flow.
2. In cases where the phone number is not added to the A2P-verified Message Service, the "send and wait for reply" feature operates as intended. Unfortunately, numerous SMS messages are being blocked due to the enforcement of A2P campaign regulations.

It is worth noting that even the example provided by Twilio in their documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-send-appointment) encounters the same issue.

Is there a potential workaround to address this situation?

Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Get answer from Twilio, if you send sms via message service, or you added your phone number into a message service, use Message Service Sig as from, not the phone number, in that way, the "send and wait for reply" widget will collect the user reply.